# MS Access Database Design Issue (One-to-Many vs. Many-to-Many Relationships)

Tags: ms-access, relational-database

I currently have an Access 2013 database composed of three tables, containing the following string fields on three separate tables:

### alert

```
alert_id (primary key)
```

### email

```
ID (primary key),
alert_id,
email_address,
date_added
```

### phone

```
ID (primary key),
alert_id,
phone_number,
date_added
```

I currently have the relationships defined as a one-to-many, connecting from the primary key `alert_id` in the `alert` table to both non-primary key `alert_id` fields in both the `email` and `phone` tables.

The data that I'll be inputing into this table generally consists of a single alert ID, which is associated with several email addresses and/or phone numbers.  I receive new information in several batches through out the day, and input it accordingly.

I have an input form that allows for the entry of one `alert_id`, one `email_address`, and one `phone_number` at a time into the database.  I also have another input form which, using subforms, allows for the entry of a single `alert_id` along with multiple entries into the `email_address` and `phone_number` fields.

The issue I'm running into is that it is a regular occurrence that I'll need to input `email_address` and `phone_number` data with a specific `alert_id` one day, and then the next day input more email and phone data with the same `alert_id`.  The way the table relationships are currently structured, with `alert_id` being a primary key, I get a hard stop when trying to input an existing `alert_id` into the form field.

Is there a way to code the form so that this won't be an issue?  I think that the current structure is properly normalized, and the issue is more with the way I'm doing the form.  However, if the database's structure isn't optimal for the use, I'm open to changing that as well.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `alert.alert_ID` from your form. There shouldn't be any need for the user to specify this field directly, and like you have laid out, it is causing issues.

Instead, use a combobox with a control source equal to your table `alert` and have the user choose which `alert_ID` they will be adding email address or phone numbers to.

If this is a brand new `alert_ID` not already specified in your combobox, add a command button next to it that will create a new `alert_ID` in your `alert` table. Also have the command button requery your combobox so the newly created `alert_ID` appears immediately (or even have the macro choose the new `alert_ID` for them). That should prevent the error of duplicate values in your primary key.

I don't see any issue with the way your tables are structured, but that's assuming the user will know how to interpret the `alert_ID` without a name or description field. The error is due to the way your form is constructed, not the underlying structure of your database.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I should have mentioned this in the OP, but the `alert_id` values are not generated by the database, they are received with the other values and input into the database.  And, since I need for the `alert_id` value to be linked with both of the other `email_address` and `phone_number` values, all three need to be on the form, I think.  Additionally, the scale involved here (the current data tables I'll be adding into the completed database hold around 10K rows) makes me disinclined to use a combobox.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Psychonaut418 So the `alert.alert_id` field is generated when a new `email.alert_id` is added to the `email` table (and the same with `phone`) using referential integrity? Is there any code running to add records to the `alert` table? Also, how does the user know which `alert_id` they need to add more contacts to?

Comment: No, right now I have the form set up so that the form is tied to the `alert.alert_id` field, with referential integrity updating the `email.alert_id` and/or `phone.alert_id` fields accordingly.  The user inputting the data receives an external email containing the `alert_id`, `email_address`, and `phone_number` that needs to be added into the database, then will input these using the form.  If they're adding new emails or phone numbers to an existing `alert_id` it will be because they've received new email/phone data in an external email that's tagged with an older `alert_id`.

Comment: @Psychonaut418 I see, I think if your form is bound to the `alert` table there won't be any option to add new contacts to an existing `alert_id` unless the user is able to know whether the `alert_id` exists already and if so, navigate to that record on the form before adding new contacts (which isn't possible if the form property "Data Entry" is set to "Yes").